# Which program was this infographic made in?

Tags: software-recommendation, chart-design

Please note the "PLUS" button to open or close more content.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from one of the MindMapping apps. It looks kind of like an old version of MindJet's MindManager, or modern output from Freemind, but could be a couple of others. A few of them can be configured to make this kind of look.

Search for Mind Mapping apps in Google.

Freemind is free, open source.

MindJet MindManager is the market dominator.

### Update:

After a quick look, I'm pretty sure that image was done in MindMeister. Here's some output from it on their marketing page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it could be MindManager, MindMeister, iThoughts or ConceptDraw MindMap. Many of mind mapping tools have this "plus" option.
[image]